# Clarification about the definition of infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am reading Introduction to real analysis by Bartle and Sherbert, 3rd edition. I find it a bit difficult in the following (page 89):

> "In elementary texts, an infinite series is sometimes "defined " to be "an expression of the form"
>   $x_1 + x_2 + ...+ x_n + ... $ (what's wrong here?)
>
> However this definition lacks clarity, since there is *a priori* no particular value that we can attach to this array of symbols, which calls for an *infinite* number of additions to be performed."

What is the clarity lacking in the elementary definition? Can some explain with examples?

Comment: Given $n$ real numbers $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, you can compute the sum $\sum_{j=1}^n x_j$. But can you perform addition infinitely many times?

Comment: Technically a series is a pair of sequences: the original sequence $(x_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ and a second sequence $(s_n)_{n\geqslant1}$, defined by $s_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^nx_k$. The series converges (a statement often written as "the series $\sum\limits_nx_n$ converges") iff the second sequence $(s_n)$ converges. When $(s_n)$ does converge, its limit is denoted by $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x_n$. Of course the first sequence $(x_n)$ can be recovered from the second sequence $(s_n)$. Ditto for sus starting at $n=0$ instead of $n=1$.

Comment: *Typo: sus > sums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to steer you a bit. I've read this book from cover to cover and love Bartle and Sherbert's writing style; but they often say things in ways that are fancier and flashier than they need to be.

Forget what they're saying and listen to me:

Let ($x_n$) be a sequence. If you take the limit of the sequence ($x_1$,   $x_1+x_2$ ,  $x_1+x_2+x_3$ , ... ), denoted by $\Sigma^\infty_1(x_n)$, it's as if you had just added together every single term of ($x_n$). See?  It's as if you just did the sum $x_1+x_2+x_3+...+.+x_k+x_{k+1}...$ of all terms of ($x_n$). Only, because $(x_n)$ has an infinite number of terms, you couldn't possibly add them all together because you'd have to do so one by one and you'd never reach the end. Thus, you have to take the limit. If this limit exists, then you know you can get within any distance $\epsilon$ of the true sum by summing up the first m terms for sufficiently large m; and sometimes, you can even determine the limit of the sum directly and then you have the value of the actual sum.

There is just one vocabulary word here: series. If ($x_n$) is a sequence, we call $\Sigma^\infty_1(x_n)$=($x_1$,   $x_1+x_2$ ,  $x_1+x_2+x_3$ , ... ) a series; because calling them both sequences gets confusing when trying to communicate. Think about it: You would never know which one someone is talking about if they call them both sequences all the time.

Adam V. Nease

Answer (score 3):

The proposed definition does not so much "lack clarity" as it **fails to be a definition at all**.

At best it defines what the *notation* for an infinite series *looks like* -- but it doesn't even make any attempt to explain what this notation *means*.

As readers of better texts we know that, for example
$$ 1 + \frac12 + \frac14 + \cdots + \frac1{2^n} + \cdots $$
denotes a particular real number, but simply "defining" an infinite series to be "an expression of this form" does nothing to explain *which* that number is. One cannot use such a "definition" to prove that the value is $2$ -- or even to argue that the value *is not* $42$, if we got into an argument with someone who said it is.

Comment: +1. Perhaps even more importantly, a series cannot be reduced to its sum, for example, $\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}\frac1{n(n+1)}$ and $\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}\frac1{2^n}$ are not the same series although $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n(n+1)}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2^n}=1$.